# Get OkHttp PUT request parameters in Servlets

Tags: java, android, servlets, jakarta-ee, okhttp

I'm making a `PUT` request using `OkHttp 4.9.1` from my Android app as below,

```
RequestBody reqBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("name", name)
        .add("phone", phone)
        .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(API_URL)
        .put(reqBody)
        .build();

new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    ...
});
```

The request comes to the server but the problem is I cannot access the parameters from the Servlet,

```
@Override
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("NAME: " + req.getParameter("name"));
    System.out.println("PARAMS: " + new HashMap(req.getParameterMap()).toString());
    System.out.println("CT: " + req.getContentType());
}
```

below is the output log from the server,

```
NAME: null
PARAMS: {}
CT: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

As you can see the parameter map is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.getParameter()` is not working in Servlets when it comes to `PUT` requests.  So this was not a problem with `OkHttp`. As to why `request.getParameter()` is not working in `doPut(...)` refer the post below,

[Servlet request.getParameter() returns null in PUT but not in POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67653731/2408342)