# Servlet request.getParameter() returns null in PUT but not in POST

Tags: java, post, servlets, jakarta-ee, put

I'm sending a `PUT` request with the `Content-Type` header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

[image: postman]

The request comes to the server but the problem is I cannot access the parameters from the Servlet,

```
@Override
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("NAME: " + req.getParameter("name"));
    System.out.println("PHONE: " + req.getParameter("phone"));
    System.out.println("CT: " + req.getContentType());
}
```

below is the output log from the server,

```
NAME: null
PHONE: null
CT: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

As you can see both parameters are `null`. But when the same thing is done in `doPost(...)` it works.

1. Why doesn't `request.getParameter()` work in `PUT`?
2. How can I get parameter values in `doPut()`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The PUT is not the same as POST. Check this if it helps.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855835/servlet-parameters-and-doput

Comment: Why have they dropped the `getParameter()` functionality from `PUT`? Why does everything have to be so complicated. :(

Comment: Anyways, you can still read the parameters from request InputStream as already mentioned in the link. Regarding the functionality drop, it is the way the servlet containers handle PUT and POST,GET. Servlet Container runtime does not generate a usable parameter map in case of PUT, so, the parameters can not be obtained as in POST where the parameter map is created.